# Regarding Auto Email sending trigger

Tags: trigger, triggercontext

Salesforce is integrated to Ipad app, when creating the order online in Ipad auto email sending trigger is working, if I create the order in offline in Ipad auto email trigger is not working, after getting the connection synchronization process will takes place that time trigger should have to work what i have to made changes in the trigger code

```
Trigger AutoEmailsending on Order (after update) 
{
    Map<Id,Order> Orderdetail = new Map<Id,Order>();
    Set<Id> Accountid = new Set<Id>();
    for(order or1 : Trigger.new)
    {
        if(or1.Status == 'Submitted' && (or1.Subtype__c =='Offer' || or1.Subtype__c =='ASP'))
        {
            Orderdetail.put(or1.id,or1);
            Accountid.add (or1.accountid);
        }
    }
 StaticResource TC = [select body from StaticResource where Name=:ResourceName];
        //Attaching Terms and conditions PDF
        Messaging.Emailfileattachment efa1 = new Messaging.Emailfileattachment();
        efa1.setFileName(TCname);
        efa1.setBody(TC.Body);
        fileAttachments.add(efa1);
        mail.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
    }
}
}
```

Please anyone guide me for the Answer

Comment: your trigger is of after update type but the requirement appears to be of after insert case.

Comment: but in online is working , why it is in offline mode @MukeshVerma

Comment: In offline mode temp id id created for the particular order, then after synchronisation it will reflects to the salesforce

Comment: offline mode do not create record in Salesforce instead records are created when sync operation happens. May be some workflow is active that initiates update operation and thereby causing trigger to work.

Comment: what is the workflow process i have to write for above scenario to initiate the trigger in offline mode,Guide me for the Answer @MukeshVerma

Comment: @MukeshVerma for that particular order i have attachment , how to add the attachment in workflow rule please guide me for the Answer

Comment: I am not asking to create a workflow. Insted just want you to consider changing this trigger to after insert. Try putting some debug statements to know flow of execution at the time of sync.

Comment: ok @MukeshVerma i will check